# Never call on Create when process is killed

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I'm building an app that works on my Nexus 7 without any problems and also on my Galaxy S2. Now I've tested it on a Galaxy S3, but somehow the memory management is far more agressive. If I press the home button and wait a few minutes, OnCreate gets called again, so I assume the process has been killed. But if the process gets killed, for this particular application, I want it to start another activity.

I could use overriding onStop and onPause, but that would cause some unwanted behaviour, looking at the Activity Lifecycle. If the process isn't killed it is fine to return to the activity.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: does that mean in the second OnCreate you want to start an other activity than in the first OnCreate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `savedInstanceState` in your `onCreate` like this:

```
if( savedInstanceState != null ) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, savedInstanceState.getString("message")+"--> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: That does the trick, since savedInstanceState is only not null when the activity has been destroyed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

By pressing the home button your activity can be destroyed if the system  has determined it needs to free some resources.

This can happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.